# safari activity window java applet class not found

Tags: java, swing, safari, applet

Update: After doing different things, somehow I managed to remove the error by changing object tag to applet tag.. Does anyone know the difference between the two? why object tag cause the error while applet tag does not?

---

This is probably a simple question but I just can't find the answer after doing some research. So, if I have a site with java applet, in safari if you look through activity window it will say not found. Why is that?
an example of a site showing like that would be
http://www.javaatwork.com/java-upload-applet/demo.html

In the activity window for safari it will show not found (on mac) or cancelled (on windows). Anyone know why is that?[image]

Answer (score 3):

I get the result shown below. The response, [`10.4.7 406 Not Acceptable`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), allows for canceling the request. You might check that the Java plugin in installed using the `Help > Installed Plug-Ins` menu. Also review your `System Preferences > Security` settings.

```
$ curl http://www.javaatwork.com/java-upload-applet/demo.html
```

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /java-upload-applet/demo.html could not be found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Possibly related: [*Mozilla Blocks Vulnerable Java Versions In Firefox*](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/12/04/03/1350223/mozilla-blocks-vulnerable-java-versions-in-firefox).

Comment: actually after changing <object> to <applet> the error is gone. Do you know the difference between the two?

Comment: No, but I use the `<applet>` tag, too.